# ImportError: cannot import name 'Graph'

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I am on windows using Anaconda with python 3.6, I have installed keras by:

```
conda install -c conda-forge keras
```

and whene i try this code

```
from keras.models import Graph
```

I get this error message:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-74d2d1fd7bad> in <module>()
----> 1 from keras.models import Graph
ImportError: cannot import name 'Graph'
```

Comment: Graph has been removed. Use the functional API.
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4661
Updated docs are given here
https://keras.io/layers/containers/

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Python issue. This is because the latest version of keras has removed Graph module from models. You can surely check the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you check this Github issue ([Why Keras remove graph model?](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2462)), you can use the following line of code:

```
from .legacy.models import Graph
```

However, it is suggested to use functional API instead. Please check [The Functional API](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/)